# Can't to fit a layout into tabcontent

Tags: android, layout, tabs

I have a problem, when I open a layout inside the tabs, exactly in a tabcontent, the layout doesn't fit with his parent and not appear completely in the screen. Is there any way control this problem? I don't know to do for resolve this.

xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Thank's.

Comment: Did you use fill_parent and wrap_content in your width and height layouts? You have to post some code, we can't guess what you are doing wrong!

Comment: I've already put the xml code! ;) Thank's

Comment: OK, what are you opening in the TabContent area?

Comment: Try android:layout_height="some_numeric_value dp" istead of wrap_content

Comment: I have three tabs, two for webviews and other for a formulary. In two webvies when orentation is landscape the width is very large for advice screen. And in the formulary when orentation is portait and landscape I have problem for to see complety his content. Thank's again! ;)

Comment: I meant the suggestion for TabWidget, just forgot to mention it ))) Did you try it?

Comment: I've tried! But the problem no is the TabWidget. I think that the problem is in FrameLayout or in tabcontainer.

Answer (score 1):

you should show us what you did in XML. Set with and height of parent layout to "Fill_parent" and for the rest you can use either of fill parent, wrap content.

Answer (score 0):

Just change Height & width with "Fill_parent". 
 andd you get what you want to do.